# CSS background color inheritance

Tags: css

I have a parent div and a child div.

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

.child {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

The child element background color looks different from `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` as it is inheriting background color from parent.

Shouldn't the background color for the child look like `rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)` as  `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)` is applied on top of `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)`?

If you are down voting please put a comment why you are down voting.

[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/0ansba7d/8/)

Comment: ))). No. They dont overlap :D. Dont think like this with css

Comment: I don't think it works like that since 0.5 and 0.5 in opacity world is not 1

Comment: Do some research on opacity and the alpha channel.

Answer (score -3):

I believe that since you are inheriting the color you can use "inherit" in the css code as follows:

```css
.container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)
}

.child container{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:inherit
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```